# Using Rails to transfer files from a remote server to another (FTP or Rsync or SCP etc..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp, file-transfer

I have a video transcode server and as a video gets transcoded **I need to send the converted versions of the video to a CDN and show my CMS admins the progresses of processes**.

At first (I guess just like most of other RoR developers :) I looked for a gem for this purpose. Honestly, I was unable to find one. This made me think of that I was missing something.

When I google around, just get '*paperclip*' and '*carrierview*' as answers. But I don't want a gem to make users upload a file to server. **I want to copy a file from my server to another server**.

I've found a native class of Ruby called [Net::SCP](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-scp-1.0.4/Net/SCP.html) after some research  and it has a progress reporting parameter. I'm using Resque for background processes. So I might use 
this.

**BUT**, when I use this block:

```
scp.upload!("/path/to/local", "/path/to/remote") do |ch, name, sent, total|   
puts "#{name}: #{sent}/#{total}" 
end
```

It calls back 'sent' parameter **VERY frequantly**. Sending about 5 update queries per second to my DB is not a good idea, I think? Is there a work around for this situation?

### So what do you suggest me to do? Is there a gem around for the purpose I ask for? Or what should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could increase the chunk size option for `Net::SCP#upload!`, as [the documentation implies](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-scp-1.0.4/Net/SCP.html#label-Progress+Reporting):

> Whenever a new chunk of data is […] sent to a file, the [block given to `upload`] will be invoked […]

And further in [`#upload`](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-scp-1.0.4/Net/SCP.html#method-i-upload):

> **`:chunk_size`** - the size of each "chunk" that should be sent. Defaults to 2048. Changing this value may improve throughput at the expense of decreasing interactivity.

… which is what you seem to want.

```rb
chunk_size = 100.kilobytes
scp.upload!(local_fname, remote_fname, chunk_size: chunk_size) do |ch, name, sent, total|   
  puts "#{name}: #{sent}/#{total}"
end
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your answer! I guess this is absoletly what I'm looking for! BUT... It's not clear to me the intervals. What 2048 actually is? Should I decrease or increase it?

Comment: Well, I've used try and fail method and find out that greater chunk size, the more latency of callbacks. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I'd guess `chunk_size` refers to the number of bytes submitted at once. So increasing (from 2k to 100k in my example) should be the way to go.